# Creating a query in mysql linking 2 tables and only displaying certain information

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, tbl_students & tbl_inv. The student table holds all information for students. I am creating an invoicing system to create and keep records for invoices (monthly) for the students. The tbl_inv can have multiple invoices for a single student but with a different date. I am trying to create an array which will list all the students with the latest invoice, total and status ordered by the newest invoice date at the top. I am fairly new to programming with mysql and php, so my apologies if my question sounds silly. This is what I have for the query.....

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_student 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_inv ON tbl_student.sid = tbl_inv.inv_sid 
  GROUP BY tbl_student.sid 
  ORDER BY tbl_inv.inv_date DESC";
```

This creates an array which has one line per student but doesn't display the latest invoice date and details.

If anyone can help I would be much appreciated :-)

**(Addition pull from direct comments to existing answer)**

This is the final query that works..

```
SELECT 
      S.*, 
      TI2.* 
   FROM 
      tbl_student S 
         LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 
                           TI.inv_sid, 
                           MAX(TI.inv_id) LatestInvoice 
                        FROM 
                           tbl_inv TI 
                        GROUP BY 
                           TI.inv_sid ) PreQuery 
            ON S.sid = PreQuery.inv_sid 
            LEFT JOIN tbl_inv TI2 
               ON PreQuery.inv_sid = TI2.inv_sid 
              AND PreQuery.LatestInvoice = TI2.inv_id 
   ORDER BY 
      TI2.inv_id ASC
```

I have students link with each other my using a field called f_link on the student table. If a student has a family member linked to them the f_link field shows the master id no. If there is no family link the field just shows a 0. With my invoicing system I am creating an invoice for a student and any family member linked to them. The current query will display no data for invoices for the family member, but they have been invoiced. I want to narrow this query down to only display students who have 0 in the f_link field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep looking and learning querying... formatting and readability is a big plus for future maintenance.  For this type of problem, ask what is the FIRST thing you need... in your case, on a per-student basis, what is the last invoice they had (regardless of the data).

```
select
      TI.inv_sid,
      MAX( TI.inv_date ) LatestInvoiceDate
   from
      tbl_inv TI
   group by
      TI.inv_sid
```

The above will give you one piece of the puzzle, and that is how many complex queries get built.  From this, you then want the student's name, and invoice details about this most recent invoice.  To do, the above query will be used in the next phase... in this case, it will get an "alias" for its result set to get the rest of the details.

```
select
      S.*,
      TI2.*
   from
      tbl_Student S
         LEFT JOIN  ( select
                            TI.inv_sid,
                            MAX( TI.invoicenumber ) LatestInvoiceNumber,
                            count(*) totalInvoicesForStudent,
                            sum( TI.Total ) as TotalAllInvoices,
                            sum( TI.Total - TI.AmountPaid) as OutstandingBalances
                         from
                            tbl_inv TI
                         group by
                            TI.inv_sid ) PreQuery
            on S.sid = PreQuery.inv_sid
            LEFT JOIN tbl_inv TI2
               on PreQuery.inv_sid = TI2.inv_sid
              AND PreQuery.LatestInvoiceNumber = TI2.invoiceNumber
   where
      s.F_Link = 0
   order by
      TI2.inv_date desc
```

So, to clarify above query

For EVERY Student (table listed first),

do a LEFT JOIN (all students regardless of ever yet having an invoice) to the "PreQuery" result set that has all students with their most recent invoice date).

If such an invoice record WAS found, do another LEFT JOIN to the invoice table AGAIN, but this time on the PreQuery "student id" and the "LatestInvoiceDate" determined for that user to the original invoice table.

Once those are all joined together, get all the fields from both the student table and the SECOND instance (TI2) invoice table for the invoice details.

Now, if you want ONLY students who HAD A MINIMUM of at least 1 invoice, just leave as "JOIN" instead of "LEFT JOIN".

Comment: That's great DRapp! Thanks for explaining too. This will help me understand complex querying (once I have digested the above).
One thing though I also have a field for the invoice total (tbl.total), it is not displaying the total. Can't figure out why ;-(
I did notice that the table also displayed multiple invoices for the same student if they had the same invoice date. Is there a way to limit this (possibly by highest invoice number?)? This is just on my test data, in normal practice I can't see this happening. Just curious and want to make if fairly bomb proof.
Thanks again,
Steve

Comment: My bad..... the reason my table was not displaying the total was because the field total in the table was 0.00. This works fine thanks. I also changed some of the dates for the same student and the table only displayed one line per student. Cheers, Steve

Comment: @Steve, as for the most recent, instead of doing max( invoice date), do max( invoice #) and join to the invoice # instead.  Should get you what you want.  In addition, I revised the query to get some other stats you may be interested in... such as # invoices, total of all of them, or outstanding balance (just guessing on what COULD be such columns in the invoice table).  Let me know if they help too.

Comment: many thanks for all the info and help. It is great to have people like yourself on this forum to help out with these issues. Much appreciated indeed. Steve

Comment: @Steve, you are welcome.  Also, as a newbie, it is common to click on the checkmark next to the answer (in addition with an up-mark) for those that help / solve your answer.  It also indicates to others that the solution is solved and they can move on to other pending questions.  It's also how reputation points are earned.  Additionally, some people don't realize, but you up-click points to comments for those found to be really useful and also give reputation points to those providing answers/comments. :)

Comment: I am a newbie here, so thanks for helping me through this process too. I believe I have confirmed everything now. All the best to you Sir :-)

Comment: I have one further question, which I wonder if you could help with. This is the final query that works..
SELECT S.*, TI2.* FROM tbl_student S LEFT JOIN (SELECT TI.inv_sid, MAX(TI.inv_id) LatestInvoice FROM tbl_inv TI GROUP BY TI.inv_sid) PreQuery ON S.sid = PreQuery.inv_sid LEFT JOIN tbl_inv TI2 ON PreQuery.inv_sid = TI2.inv_sid AND PreQuery.LatestInvoice = TI2.inv_id ORDER BY TI2.inv_id ASC.

Comment: I have students link with each other my using a field called f_link on the student table. If a student has a family member linked to them the f_link field shows the master id no. If there is no family link the field just shows a 0. With my invoicing system I am creating an invoice for a student and any family member linked to them. The current query will display no data for invoices for the family member, but they have been invoiced. I want to narrow this query down to only display students who have 0 in the f_link field.

Comment: I have tried slipping in WHERE S.f_link=0, but it is throwing up an error. I am guessing that you cant use a LEFT JOIN and WHERE together. Am I trying to do the impossible? Thanks, Steve

Comment: @Steve, see revised answer.  I actually updated your original question with readability of your final working query.  The WHERE clause would appear immediately above the order by -- same level as the primary "FROM" clause, not with the other left joins / on conditions.